# Como puedo sumar elementos de una lista en python con condicionantes

Tags: python

tengo un inconveniente usando python a la hora de sumar elementos en una lista. Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
productos=[
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '10','egreso': '-15','consumidor': 'Juan'},
{'codigo': '2','ingreso': '5','egreso': '-10','consumidor': 'Jose'},
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '15','egreso': '-20','consumidor': 'Juan'},
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '7','egreso': '-7','consumidor': 'Jose'}
]
```

Estoy intentando hacer una suma de los valores correspondientes a egreso tomando en cuenta el valor del codigo y el valor del consumidor es decir que el resultado final sea

```
productos=[
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '25','egreso': '-35','consumidor': 'Juan'},
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '7','egreso': '-7','consumidor': 'Jose'},
{'codigo': '2','ingreso': '5','egreso': '-10','consumidor': 'Jose'},
]
```

de momento he intentado creando un diccionario auxiliar en el que ir sumando los valores para luego reasignarlos nuevamente a una lista de la siguiente manera

```
aux = {}
for producto in productos:
    x = producto['codigo']
    if x not in aux:
        aux[x] = producto
    else:
        ingreso, egreso = float(aux[x]['ingreso']), float(aux[x]['egreso'])
        aux[x]['ingreso'], aux[x]['egreso'] = f"{float(producto['ingreso']) + ingreso:.1f}", f"{float(producto['egreso']) + egreso :.1f}"
productos = list(aux.values())
```

Sin embargo de esta forma no se toma en cuenta el valor de consumidor

Comment: Y cual sería la pregunta? Podrías agregar lo que has intentado, aunque no funcione, por favor?

Comment: Le edite la pregunta con lo que he intentado por el momento

Comment: Gracias! Siempre es bueno demostrar que eres parte del esfuerzo por resolver tu propia duda ;)

Comment: veo respuestas con demasiado codigo, que te parece hacer primero `my_fun = lambda x: x['consumidor']=='Juan' and x['codigo']=='1' `, y luego la lista filtrada es: `productos_filtrados = list(filter(my_fun, productos))`

Comment: Puedes editar el filtro a tu gusto, y para terminar puedes hacer `suma_egresos = sum([float(x['egreso'] for x in productos_filtrados)])`

Answer (score 1):

Qué tal si para facilitar un poco la lógica, se hace un diccionario temporal con un índice `codigo_consumidor` e ir acumulando los valores respectivos en esa coincidencia.
Ver [dic.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```py
aux = {}
for prod in productos:
    key = prod['codigo'] + '_' + prod['consumidor']
    ingreso = aux.get(key, {}).get('ingreso', 0) + float(prod['ingreso'])
    egreso  = aux.get(key, {}).get('egreso', 0) + float(prod['egreso'])
    aux[key] = {'codigo':prod['codigo'], 'ingreso': ingreso, 'egreso': egreso, 'consumidor':prod['consumidor']}
```

Hasta aquí `aux` tendrá este formato:

```
{
  '1_Juan': {'codigo': '1', 'ingreso': 25.0, 'egreso': -35.0, 'consumidor': 'Juan'}, 
  '2_Jose': {'codigo': '2', 'ingreso': 5.0, 'egreso': -10.0, 'consumidor': 'Jose'}, 
  '1_Jose': {'codigo': '1', 'ingreso': 7.0, 'egreso': -7.0, 'consumidor': 'Jose'}
}
```

Para convertirlo otra vez a lista de diccionarios, se recorre `aux` y se usa solo el valor:

```
productos = [v for k, v in aux.items()]
```

Comment: Yo lo había planteado como tú (pero en una función) y para poder ordenar por código utilicé:  `return sorted(list(codigo_consum.values()), key=lambda x: x["codigo"])`

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad es la siguiente.

1. Primero recorres tus datos y vas creando con ellos otra estructura, que sería un diccionario cuyas claves son los códigos diferentes, y cuyos valores son a su vez otros diccionarios anidados. En estos diccionarios internos las claves son los consumidores (para el correspondiente código) y los valores son  una lista con los datos de ingreso y egreso de cada uno.
2. Una vez tienes esa estructura es más fácil lograr lo que buscas, pues esa estructura ya tiene agrupados los datos como los deseas, y basta sumarlos

Para crear esa estructura el código sería el siguiente:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

productos=[
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '10','egreso': '-15','consumidor': 'Juan'},
{'codigo': '2','ingreso': '5','egreso': '-10','consumidor': 'Jose'},
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '15','egreso': '-20','consumidor': 'Juan'},
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '7','egreso': '-7','consumidor': 'Jose'}
]


data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for p in productos:
  cod = p["codigo"]
  cons = p["consumidor"]
  ing = float(p["ingreso"])
  egr = float(p["egreso"])
  data[cod][cons].append((ing, egr))
```

El resultado de ejecutar lo anterior producirá un diccionario "ya agrupado" como el siguiente:

```py
{
  '1': {'Jose': [(7.0, -7.0)],
        'Juan': [(10.0, -15.0), (15.0, -20.0)]
        },
  '2': {'Jose': [(5.0, -10.0)]}
}
```

Como ves, para cada codigo hay otro diccionario cuyas claves son los consumidores. Y para cada uno una lista de tuplas que son (ingreso, egreso) respectivamente.

Y para procesarlos y crear la lista que buscas sería así:

```py
result = []
for cod, d in data.items():
  for cons, values in d.items():
    ingreso = 0
    egreso = 0
    for ing, egr in values:
      ingreso += ing
      egreso += egr
    result.append(dict(codigo=cod, ingreso=ingreso, egreso=egreso, consumidor=cons))
```

En este caso el resultado es

```py
[{'codigo': '1', 'ingreso': 25.0, 'egreso': -35.0, 'consumidor': 'Juan'},
 {'codigo': '1', 'ingreso': 7.0, 'egreso': -7.0, 'consumidor': 'Jose'},
 {'codigo': '2', 'ingreso': 5.0, 'egreso': -10.0, 'consumidor': 'Jose'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa. Usar la función [groupby](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) del modulo itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

productos=[
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '10','egreso': '-15','consumidor': 'Juan'},
{'codigo': '2','ingreso': '5','egreso': '-10','consumidor': 'Jose'},
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '15','egreso': '-20','consumidor': 'Juan'},
{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '7','egreso': '-7','consumidor': 'Jose'}
]

keyfunc = lambda item:(item["codigo"], item["consumidor"])

prod_ordenados = sorted(productos, key=keyfunc)
prod_agrupados = groupby(prod_ordenados, key=keyfunc)

nuevos_productos = []

for (codigo, consumidor), grupo in prod_agrupados:
    aux = {'codigo':codigo, 'ingreso':0, 'egreso':0, 'consumidor':consumidor}
    
    for producto in grupo:
        aux["ingreso"] += float(producto["ingreso"])
        aux["egreso"] += float(producto["egreso"])

    nuevos_productos.append(aux)


for producto in nuevos_productos:
    print(producto)
```

---

Lo explicaré por partes.

```
keyfunc = lambda item:(item["codigo"], item["consumidor"])
```

Creamos una función que se encarge de recibir un producto y lo convierta en una tupla que contenga el código y el consumidor. Esto luego será usado para ordenar y agrupar la lista de productos según dichas tuplas.

```
prod_ordenados = sorted(productos, key=keyfunc)
```

Ordenamos la lista de productos usando las tuplas devueltas por keyfunc. Esto lo hacemos por que, por ejemplo, si groupby encuentra un iterable así: `11221`, te lo agruparía como `11 22 1`.

```
prod_agrupados = groupby(prod_ordenados, key=keyfunc)
```

Agrupamos los productos usando las tuplas nuevamente. Esto resulta en un iterador que podríamos representar a modo ilustrativo así:

```
('1', 'Juan') ---> [{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '10','egreso': '-15','consumidor': 'Juan'}
                    {'codigo': '1','ingreso': '15','egreso': '-20','consumidor': 'Juan'}]

('1', 'Jose') ---> [{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '7','egreso': '-7','consumidor': 'Jose'}]

('1', 'Juan') ---> [{'codigo': '1','ingreso': '15','egreso': '-20','consumidor': 'Juan'}]
```

Yo creo que el resto lo lograrás entender perfectamente. Cualquier duda que tengas dime c: